# Missing name servers reported by parent

Tags: dns, nameserver

I'm changing servers and using private/custom nameservers. I've set up those I think it is using glue records (so assigning an ip address to a custom ns).

It's been over 24 hours.

When I run it through intodns I get:

```
Missing nameservers reported by parent
```

And

```
Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers
```

How to resolve this, like I mentioned I have created my nameservers with the correct ips and have added them to WHM as well.

In the past my reseller created did something and that fixed it. What are the next steps to fix this?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/701526/missing-nameservers-reported-by-parent-and-your-nameservers). If you're not able to change this on your own, then ask your provider for help.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that question when posted it. Feel free to vote to close it.

Comment: I'm closing this question because you indicate you found your answer elsewhere.   This question is not likely to get a new or better answer here.